# How can I update a field on a user profile with Drush

Tags: users, drush

I'm creating users with `user-create` but I have added extra fields to the user like membership number.

Is there a way to update that field with a number when I create the user?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Drush Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/drush_entity). Here is a quote from its project page:

> ... you can query the entity system available for Drupal 8, 7 and (some of) 6.